# Does libGDX support the Xbox One controller?

Tags: libgdx, controllers

I just bought a Xbox one controller and i'd like to test my game with it. I use the `Controllers` extension from libGDX and it works fine, at least with my PS3 controller.

I get some weird results when i'm polling the axis of the controller with libGDX. The values are ok for Y axies but not for X ones. I mean, for X axis, values are really weird, sometimes, when the stick is fully pushed to the left, the value is not even negative, same goes for the right, sometimes value is negative. I don't know why but values seems inconsistent for X axies, Y axies work fine.

Concerning buttons, they are all detected except for the dpad.

I am using the drivers available [here](http://majornelson.com/2014/06/05/pc-drivers-for-the-xbox-one-controller-available-now/). I tested the controller with several games, it works fine so i think it's related to libGDX.

Do you think the Xbox One controller is not supported yet? Can it be a driver issue? Should I use another way to poll controller states? If yes, is there a good and up to date library to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of controller input. There is DirectInput, and there is XInput. PS3 controllers use DirectInput, while XInput is Microsoft's choice (they made it for the xbox, I think). Both of these controllers are supported in LibGDX. However, they are different in how you get data. For example, DirectInput doesn't handle analog trigger buttons, while xInput does.

Xbox One controllers, with the current drivers, just simulate Xbox 360 controllers, and use XInput. You need the correct mapping for it to use it in LibGDX (just like OUYA; except Badlogic supplies the OUYA mappings and not the 360 mappings).

I found this mapping floating around the internet for Xbox 360 controllers:

```
public class Xbox360Pad
{
   /*
    * It seems there are different versions of gamepads with different ID Strings.
    * Therefore its IMO a better bet to check for:
    * if (controller.getName().toLowerCase().contains("xbox") &&
                  controller.getName().contains("360"))
    * 
    * Controller (Gamepad for Xbox 360)
      Controller (XBOX 360 For Windows)
      Controller (Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows)
      Controller (Xbox wireless receiver for windows)
      XBOX 360 For Windows (Controller)
      Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver
      Xbox Receiver for Windows (Wireless Controller)
      Xbox wireless receiver for windows (Controller)
    */
   //public static final String ID = "XBOX 360 For Windows (Controller)";
   public static final int BUTTON_X = 2;
   public static final int BUTTON_Y = 3;
   public static final int BUTTON_A = 0;
   public static final int BUTTON_B = 1;
   public static final int BUTTON_BACK = 6;
   public static final int BUTTON_START = 7;
   public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_UP = PovDirection.north;
   public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN = PovDirection.south;
   public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT = PovDirection.east;
   public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT = PovDirection.west;
   public static final int BUTTON_LB = 4;
   public static final int BUTTON_L3 = 8;
   public static final int BUTTON_RB = 5;
   public static final int BUTTON_R3 = 9;
   public static final int AXIS_LEFT_X = 1; //-1 is left | +1 is right
   public static final int AXIS_LEFT_Y = 0; //-1 is up | +1 is down
   public static final int AXIS_LEFT_TRIGGER = 4; //value 0 to 1f
   public static final int AXIS_RIGHT_X = 3; //-1 is left | +1 is right
   public static final int AXIS_RIGHT_Y = 2; //-1 is up | +1 is down
   public static final int AXIS_RIGHT_TRIGGER = 4; //value 0 to -1f
}
```